# Laravel: migrate:refresh deosn't work

Tags: php, laravel, migrate

I learn Laravel from udemy.com and I have a problem with migrate:refresh command. So, when I try use it I'll see information

> Array to string conversion
>   I try solve my problem so propably I made new mistakes so it's my code:
>   Into UserTableSeeder

```
    public function run()
{
    App\User::create([
        'name' => 'Kati',
        'email' => 'hello@hello.pl',
        'password' => bcrypt('password'),
        'admin' => 1
    ]);
    App\Profile::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'avatar' => 'link to avatar',
        'about' => 'Interested description',
        'youtube' => 'youtube.com',
        'facebook' => 'facebook.com'
    ]);
}
```

Into migrations

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->text('about');
        $table->string('youtube');
        $table->string('facebook');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->boolean('admin')->default(0);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I tryed clone my respository from github and refreshing but I had this some problem.

Comment: check `$user->id` is valid value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
public function run()
{
    $user = App\User::create([
        'name' => 'Kati',
        'email' => 'hello@hello.pl',
        'password' => bcrypt('password'),
        'admin' => 1
    ]);

    App\Profile::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'about' => 'Interested description',
        'youtube' => 'youtube.com',
        'facebook' => 'facebook.com'
    ]);
}
```

In your run statement your referencing in the `App\Profile` creation process the variable `$user->id`. However, it is not instantiated yet.
In addition, you are trying to add an avatar to your profile, therefore you should add this to the `Profile`-table or, like I did it, delete it from your seeder.

Comment: Can you provide some more details about the error? Have you tried the changed code (without the avatar)?

Comment: Yes. Like I said I clone my previous repository without Profile and it doesn't work too. php artisan migrate work, migrate:fresh too. Can you see my code? Link is in my previous message

Comment: Change line 31 in  file `database/migrations/2018_01_01_205508_create_post_tag_table.php` from `Schema::drop(['post_tag']);` to `Schema::dropIfExists('post_tag');`. The code above works without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in my  seeder:

```
'user_id' =>\App\User::pluck('id')->random();
```